# Prove that the solution for $y'=y^3(1-\tan^2(\arcsin(y)))$ , $y(0)= {\pi \over 8}$ , is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I got this problem to prove, and I assume I need to use the existence and uniqueness theorem for non-linear ODE's, so I set $y' = f(x,y)$ and differentiating in respect to $y$ gives: $f_y(x,y)$.

And both of them are continuous at $y=\Large  {\pi \over 8}$.

But from this point on I don't really know what I'm doing, how do I get a solution? And how do I check if it is bounded?

I'd be happy for some explanation and a correct solution, I need to know how to prove similar problems for my upcoming test.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the right-hand side is simply
$$
y^3\left(1-\frac{y^2}{1-y^2}\right),
$$
which has the roots $0$ and $\pm1/\sqrt2$. Since $\pi/8\in(0,1/\sqrt2)$, your solution "lives" between the two equilibrium points $0$ and $1/\sqrt2$ and thus it is bounded.

Note: the right-hand side is not defined at $x=\pm1$ but you never reach these points.

Comment: How did u get the right hand side to be: $y^3\left(1-\frac{y^2}{1-y^2}\right)$ ?  I got something else :O

Comment: After you got the right hand side as it is : $y^3\left(1-\frac{y^2}{1-y^2}\right),$ i understand the rest of it, that's what i was aiming for, but I'm still trying and not getting this. I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: With some trigonometry you get $\tan(\arcsin y)=y/\sqrt{1-y^2}$.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $y=0$ and $y=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ are solutions of the general differential equation (without the initial condition). Now use Picard–Lindelöf theorem (Cauchy-Lipschitz) observing that 
$$0<\dfrac{\pi}{8}<\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sin^{-1}y=\theta\iff \sin \theta=y$
$$\tan\theta=\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos\theta}=\frac{\sin \theta}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}}=\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}$$
$$\tan(\sin^{-1}y)=\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}$$
Now, we have $$y'=y^3\left(1-\tan^2(\sin^{-1}y)\right)$$
setting the value of $\tan(\sin^{-1}y)$,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y^3\left(1-\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\right)^2\right)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y^3\left(\frac{1-2y^2}{1-y^2}\right)$$
$$\left(\frac{1-y^2}{y^3(1-2y^2)}\right)\ dy=dx$$
$$\int \left(\frac{1}{y^3}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{2y}{1-2y^2}\right)\ dy=\int dx$$
$$\int \frac{1}{y^3}\ dy+\int \frac{1}{y}\ dy-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{d(1-2y^2)}{1-2y^2}\ dy=\int dx$$